# Правильно ли создал я констуктор в c++

Tags: c++, конструктор

Правильно ли создал я конструктор CBraidedFishingLine?

```
BraidedFishingLine.cpp

#include "pch.h"
#include "BraidedFishingLine.h"

using namespace std;

/**
* Constructor
* 
* \param double fiberBreakingStrenght, fiber breaking streanght
* \param int numStrands, number of strands in the braid
* \param double stretchFactor, the stretch factor of the underlying fiber (must be >1.0)
*/
CBraidedFishingLine::CBraidedFishingLine(double fiberBreakingStrength, int numStrands, double stretchFactor) : CFishingLine(fiberBreakingStrength, stretchFactor)
{
    numStrands = mNumStrands;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Поскольку в определении `CBraidedFishingLine::CBraidedFishingLine(...)` вы не указали, какой конструктор нужно вызвать для родителя `CFishingLine`, компилятор пытается вызвать конструктор без параметра, которого у вас нет (он генерируется автоматически только если не писать для класса никаких своих конструкторов).

Решение: сказать компилятору, что нужно использовать конструктор с двумя параметрами:

```
CBraidedFishingLine::CBraidedFishingLine(double fiberBreakingStrength, int numStrands, double stretchFactor)
    : CFishingLine(fiberBreakingStrength, stretchFactor), mNumStrands(numStrands)
{}
```

Comment: За что минус? На простые вопросы нельзя отвечать?